# S4 in safe mode, Odin on restart

Tags: rooting, safe-mode

Last night my phone was running slow so I restarted it, when it went to turn back on however it came to a screen with a warning about loading a custom OS and I had the option to either continue by pressing volume up and to decline by doing to opposite. It took several times of me doing this to turn it back on. At that point when I turned it on it was not in safe mode so I went to restart it again to see if I would run into the same issue and I did repeating the same steps as before. Finally it cam back on but in safe mode so I turned it off again after doing a factory reset hoping that would work. Now I am in safe mode and unable to use any downloaded apps or pictures and I cannot delete any files.

I was looking into rooting my phone a while ago but as I have no compute at the moment I decided to not do it after all and because it looked too complicated. I had not turned my device off since then until last night. I don't believe I downloaded anything but I'm not sure because it was more than a month ago. If there is a way I can fix this without bringing it to Verizon or even if I can root it and then unroot it to bring it back to normal. Or just keep it rooted if uprooting it is too risky.